# How to Connect Live SQL Database to Android App

Tags: php, android, sql-server

I am going to develop a simple app. My app will communicate with a live database with the help of PHP web services. While testing my app locally everything was working good. But not when I moved to live server (my database and web service files are hosted in Live server ((i.e) GoDaddy).

```
<?php  
 require "db_config.php";  

 $user_name=$_POST['login_name'];
 $user_pass=$_POST['login_pass'];
 $sql_query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "select * from user_auth where user_name='".$user_name."' and user_pass ='".$user_pass."'" , array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));  

 if(sqlsrv_num_rows($sql_query)>0)  
 {  
    echo "Login Success..Welcome";  
 }  
 else  
 {   
     echo "Login Failed.......Try Again..";  
 }  
 ?>
```

This is the code to test the login activity. After I run this I am getting this error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18452 [code] => 18452 [2] =>
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed.
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed.
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. )
[1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18452 [code] => 18452
[2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed.
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ) )
```

I Excepting while getting this problem in locally to change the some configuration in my Local SQL Management Studio Software, and also I can use some DLL files like a (make a changes in PHP.ini file)

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

This is for local machine but when I work with live database, how to config my online database? If there is any possible way to use DLL files like a local machine? If not how to config?

db_config.php

```
<?php
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testdb_mms");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Like the error says, you can't use AD authentication. Your connection is done outside the code you have attached, maybe in db_config.php

Comment: Thanks for Response @JamesZ , I attached my db_config file, In post only i miss that. Then Which Authentication to use?

Comment: Use SQL Server authentication, you'll need to create a separate user / login for that.

Comment: where? In my Hosted Database?

Comment: Yes, in the database you're trying to connect to.

Comment: already i have one user for my database, and there is no option for Specified SQL Authentication user

Comment: At least according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) there is.

Comment: okay Thank you , I will bro

Answer (score 0):

fix it to pass two more parameters(like user information)

```
<?php
//check all parameters
$serverName = "server_name"; 
$uid = "testuser";   
$pwd = "V*****";  
$databaseName = "testdb_mms";

//check config
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$databaseName); 

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```